# Removing a capital A with circumflex (Â)

Tags: java, unicode

I wrote a code for getting latitude and longitude, however, the values are printed with an "Â". Is there any way to remove this character?
A search revealed that it has a Unicode address of U+00C2, but using string.replace threw errors.
Is there any way to delete this character?
Code:

```
import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
class findlatlon {
    static String code = " ";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //gets the city
        out.println("enter city, add plus between multiple words");
        String term = sc.nextLine();

        try {URL url = new URL("http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=" + term + "&country=");

            URLConnection ucl = url.openConnection();
            InputStream stream = ucl.getInputStream();
            int i;
            //the string in which the html code will be stored
            code = " ";
            while ((i=stream.read())!= -1) {
                code += Character.toString((char)i);
            }
            //printing the html, only for testing
            System.out.print(code);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        int i = 0;
        char ch = ' ';
        String lon = " ";
        String lat = " ";
        for (i = 0 ;i < code.length() ; i++) {
            ch = code.charAt(i);
            if (ch == '\u00B0') {
                break;
            }
        }
        int j;
        char ch2 =  ' ';

        for (j = i; i > 0; j--) {
            ch2 = code.charAt(j);
            if (ch2 =='N' || ch2 == 'S') {
                break;
            }
        }
        char ch3 = ' ';
        int k = 0;
        for (k = j; k < 45800; k++) {
            ch3 = code.charAt(k);
            if (ch3 != '<') {
                lat += ch3;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        char ch4 = ' ';
        int z;
        for (z = k; z < 45000; z++) {
            ch4 = code.charAt(z);
            if (ch4 == 'W' || ch4 == 'E') {
                break;
            }
        }
        int y;
        char ch5 = ' ';
        for (y = z; y < 54000; y++) {
            ch5 = code.charAt(y);
            if (ch5 == '<') {
                break;
            } else {
                lon += ch5;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(lat);
        System.out.println(lon);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 S 33Â° 52' 4''
 E 151Â° 12' 26''
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). *"but using string.replace threw errors"* 1. Show us that attempt to use `replace` (which is the right tool). 2. ***Always*** quote the *exact* error message you got.

Comment: I tried (in C#) and got a perfectly readable response reading the returned bytes as UTF8. May you should [use this site's services](https://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) instead of screen scraping their search page very likely rendering your current problem obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but using string.replace threw errors

There's no reason `replace` should have any error with this.

```
str = str.replace("Â", "");
```

or

```
str = str.replace("\u00C2", "");
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/k9enqL)

---

That said, see [Filburt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593380/removing-a-capital-a-with-circumflex-%c3%82/56593451#comment99764280_56593380). Those characters are a side effect of reading the page with the wrong text encoding. (More about text encodings [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).) If you read it with the right encoding, or use the API they provide, you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: turns out i was using the wrong escape sequence for unicode.
this worked, thanks!